# Should i delete a moved from dynamic pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, move

I understand how to move an object, for example:

```
int a(5), b(6);
int c(std::move(a)); // move constructor
c = std::move(b);    // move assignment
```

I understand the common implementation of a custom move constructor (which takes the ownership of a dynamic pointer and sets the moved-from pointer to `nullptr`.)

But I haven't found anything about moving a dynamically allocated pointer itself.  I need confirmation that the following code is legal:

```
int *p(new int(42));
int val(std::move(*p));
delete p; // I think this is no longer necessary. Is it?
```

So, is it allowed to move a dynamic pointer?

Comment: To put it very, very simply -- normal pointers are dumb. They don't have or need move semantics because they're just a dumb pointer. They don't ever really "own" anything and they don't ever automatically free anything except themselves (that is, the pointer, not the thing pointed to). You called `new`. You either have to call `delete` or have something that can call `delete` for you take ownership of the thing you allocated. This code does neither, so it leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::move` does not move anything. It merely casts an l-value reference to an r-value reference.

In the example you give, the pointer `p` has not moved anywhere.

BTW. please don't deal in raw pointers - use a `std::unique_ptr` instead.

This allocates memory for an int, initialises the int to the value of 42 and stores the address of that memory in p.

```
int *p(new int(42));
```

---

This casts the int pointed to by `p` to an `int&&` and then constructs the int `val` from that r-value reference. Since int is an integral type, a construction from an r-value (i.e. a move) is equivalent to a copy (this is mandated in the standard)

```
int val(std::move(*p));
```

---

Yes, this is still necessary.

```
delete p;// i think this is no longer necessary. is it ?
```

Comment: Does it mean that I do not need to `delete` `p` anymore if `p` hasn't `moved` anywhere? Please help me understand, thanks

Comment: edit : in fact, i have a unique pointer and i want to know if i can pass it to a function like this : foo(std::move(*(ptr.release())))

Comment: ok, i understand. I should always consider move as a constructor behavior and not as a memory displacement.

Comment: @Cevik - correct. `std::move` is a cast which invites the code to prevent a copy if possible (i.e. you have either written a move constructor or allowed the compiler to write one for you). It has no effect on integral values - only objects.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, your code essentially copy the value of one integer to anther. You are not moving the pointer, you are moving the integer the pointer points to.

```
int a = 42;
int b = std::move(a);

std::cout << a << " : " << b << std::endl; // prints 42 : 42
```

Moving an integer is copying them.

Even if you moved the pointer, the value of the pointer of copied:

```
int* a = new int{42};
int* b = std::move(a);

std::cout << *a << " : " << *b << std::endl; // prints 42 : 42
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == b) << std::endl; // prints true
```

So moving raw pointers are copying them too.
You will still need to delete the `p` pointer.

For every new, there's a delete.

If you don't want to delete it yourself, consider [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which is aware about move semantics.

Built-in type such as raw pointer, int, floats are not aware of move semantics and moving them will simply copying them.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the use of move semantics is trivial, since you are only using primitive types and raw pointers. `std::move` is really doing nothing.

Move semantics make the difference when your objects belong to a class that supports move operations (move constructor, move assignment, etc...), or interact with other classes/ functions that do so.

Tipically, after you have move from an object (which is *not* the result of `std::move` itself, but the result of the subsequent call), the object is still alive and in a valid state, although it has been deprived of any managed content. Distruction of the objects still remains to be done, it's still a living object.

Note that you rarely see move semantics with raw pointers. It is common to see it with automatic storage objects, or smart pointers. And that's just because is the scenario where move semantics play well with.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Original post happens to use primitive integer as an example, and it happens to be a special case. The key is what the function that ```std::move``` passed to does.